# Force to HTTPS doesn't preserve URL

Tags: php, url, url-rewriting

I have this PHP code to force HTTPS (I am aware I could also use `.htaccess`).

```
if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'on') {
    if(!headers_sent()) {
        header("Status: 301 Moved Permanently");
        header(sprintf(
            'Location: https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
        ));
        exit();
    }
}
```

This changes this URL

```
http://website/foo/
```

To

```
https://website/index.php
```

But changes this URL

```
http://website/foo/bar?this=that
```

To

```
https://website/foo/bar?this=that
```

Why is this happening, and how can I get only change to HTTPS without losing the URL

Comment: I suggest clearing your browser cache and test that first URL again. It is possible that an older redirect was cached by your browser and is redirecting to that old cached page.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Tried and still giving the same behavior

Comment: OK, other than that, are you sure it is redirecting to `/index.php` and not redirecting to `/foo/` which then redirects again to `/index.php`? This could be the result of your site not finding `/foo/` or having an error and doing a second redirect. You can usually turn on the developer tools and on the network tab select "preserve navigation" or similar to see each request/redirect.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn I can navigate to https://website/foo with no issue.

Comment: Well, other than that, I would just start dumping out variables instead of redirecting to make sure that `REQUEST_URI` has what you think it does. Make sure that you are sending a header with the correct values. If you are, then there is something else doing an additional redirect or it is cached. If you are seeing `index.php` in `REQUEST_URI`, then check `$_SERVER` for other variables that might have what you need.